# Мне нужно узнать transform.position.x когда player соприкасается с колайдером

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть код:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

    if (other.tag == "BlockEmpty")
    { 
        
    }
}
```

Так вот я хочу что бы когда он прикасался к тегу, то я узнавал transform.position.x этого объекта. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Прикасался к тегу... К тегу... Понимаете, да? К тегу! Прикасался! Ладно, допустим, опустим. А в чем проблема? Метод OnTriggerEnter вызывается сам при входе в trigger. Вы делаете проверку. И если условие выполняется, то получаете позицию кого хотите с помощью `объект.transform.position.x`. Если хотите узнать позицию второго объекта (С которым столкнулись), то `other.gameObect.transform.position.x`

Answer (score 0):

OnTriggerEnter принимает в себя аргумент. Он у вас называется other это колайдер того объекта, которого коснулся персонаж. У типа колайдер есть свойство transform. И это transform, того объект, которого коснулся персонаж.